# Was First Contact Day with First Warp a coincidence?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-first-contact

The Vulcan survey ship was passing by Earth on April 5, 2063 and detected a warp signature from Earth.

But, there were also two warp signatures from Earth on April 4: The Enterprise E and a Borg sphere. The T'plana-Hath didn’t see those warp signatures, because according to Picard (and history) the survey ship would be passing by on April 5th.

I had assumed the Vulcans were sort of watching Earth. Memory Alpha does confirm this. But because they missed two large warp signatures already, it seems that if the first flight of the Phoenix flew on any other day, the Vulcans would not have known Earth was warp capable. What if Phoenix first flight launched May 3? IOW the fact that the survey ship didn’t see Enterprise or Borg warp signatures on April 4 leads me to believe they were not *continuously* watching Earth.

We know the Vulcans had been watching Earth for decades.
We know the Vulcan survey ship watching Sputnik in 1957 was *not* a coincidence (Ent: Carbon Creek).

The Vulcans were “passing by on that launch day”, and I’m assuming this Vulcan survey ship had a logical reason for being there at that time.

So was it a pure coincidence that first contact and first warp flight happened together in 2063?

Comment: Did Enterprise E and Borg sphere use warp drive near Earth in 2063?

Comment: BTW, Vulcans were indeed watching humans since 1957 (launch of Sputnik 1) as mentioned in *Star Trek: Enterprise* TV series.

Comment: It doesn’t matter if they used warp drive, the warp coils emit neutrinos whenever they are on. In *Azati Prime* Archer recognizes Degra’s Xindi ship by its signature while the ship was entering orbit. Worf had to mask Enterprise’s signature while they were in orbit. Both warp-capable ships had a signature on April 4

Comment: I assumed it was “frequent” or even constant observation because of our eugenics WWIII. Guess not?

Comment: The question whether First Contact was a coincidence or not is obviously impossible to prove in the canon, so any answer can only be opinion based. Therefore, I'm VTC as such.

Comment: @Rebel-Scum - Vulcans deliberately sent a survey ship to watch Sputnik launch in 1957, and that became canon in *Enterprise: Carbon Creek.* It's unreasonable to assume the purpose for the Vulcan survey ship watching Phoenix in 2063 will not also be found in canon. Canon has precedent that Vulcans were actively watching Earth for many decades.

Comment: @Edlothiad please let me know how Vulcans deliberately observing the Sputnik in 1957 is obviously canon while Vulcans deliberately observing Phoenix in 2063 is obviously an opinion? The Vulcan survey ship was not randomly wandering around (did I mention they are Vulcans?). Please see [my full explanation](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12775/this-answer-is-in-canon-please-review-the-opinion-based-decision)

Comment: @VogonPoet The fact that the Vulcans only make first contact with warp-capable species is of course by design (and well-known), but the fact that first contact happened on that specific day was clearly a coincidence within the canon as far as I know and not due to the whims/design of some being or organization, ie the Vulcans didn't aim to make contact that exact day! Hence, in the 1st case the question is pointless, in the 2nd it's opinion-based as we cannot really explain coincidences.

Comment: I think this is answerable. The Vulcans made first contact because they detected a warp signature, hence the fact that the first flight and first contact happened almost simultaneously wasn't a coincidence. That being said, the stated purpose of the survey ship was to carry out a scheduled(?) long-term survey of the Sol system and hence it was merely a coincidence that a Vulcan ship was in the vicinity, but not much of a coincidence since they were regularly dropping by.

Comment: @Edlothiad - does it make sense now? Do you understand the Sputnik precedent in canon?

Answer (score 4):

The Borg sphere was destroyed very quickly after arriving in the 21st Century, and the Enterprise masked their warp signature while in orbit of Earth - so that is why they weren't detected.

As for the timing of the first warp flight - well... yeah, it was a coincidence - but it still had to happen.

Picard knew when the first warp flight would take place so that it would catch the Vulcan's interest because he had a historical record that said it would happen at that time. If it didn't happen at that time, then the future (Picard's present) would have been altered. From his description it's strongly implied that the Vulcan ship was simply passing by on its way to somewhere else - but, as we see the Enterprise do on many episodes, they detected something interesting in the Sol system that warranted a diversion. If the flight of the Phoenix hadn't occurred at the right time, they would have just kept going on to their original destination.

The ship that detected the flight of the Phoenix and landed was a survey ship - it might have been flying a regular route near the Sol system. Then again, they might not have been. Eventually, though, the Vulcans would probably have encountered warp-speeding humans - although at a much later date, and history would have played out very differently to the 24th Century.

Comment: This is good except you have a warp signature whenever the warp coils are online. You don’t have to be traveling at warp. That’s why Worf had to mask it while in orbit. Warp signatures are caused by the neutrino emissions.

Comment: @VogonPoet warp signatures are caused by plot and writers, nothing more nothing less.  I think you are taking it too seriously.

Comment: Every now and then there’s a method to the madness, ya gotta ask.

Comment: @Moo Welcome to SFF, where we treat everything seriously :D

Comment: Everything can be reduced to the whim of the writers. A point was raised, which wasn't addressed. If you don't care at all about canon explanations, I'm not sure why you're here.

Comment: @HamSandwich if you are talking to me, I can think of a dozen examples of "warp signatures" involving different technobabble across the different ST series, and many examples of said warp signatures being masked in various ways.  My issue was with the fairly rigid way in which Vogon Poet says these things work as if it were incontrovertible fact, when the very series we are talking about thinks otherwise.  Hence my comment about plot and writers.

Comment: I'm sorry, Moo. I misunderstood. I'll restrict myself to quarters for the remainder of the evening as punishment.